# compatibility of declared variables

Tags: types, ada

I have here a question: 6. Ada supports named equivalence. Given the declaration:

```
A: array(1..10) of integer;
B: array(1..10) of integer;
```

Are A and B compatible? What if we declare this as

```
A, B: array(1..10) of integer;
```

Are A and B compatible? Yet another way of declaring this is

```
Type array10 is array(1..10) of integer;
A, B: array 10;
```

Are A and B compatible? If Ada supports structural equivalence, what will be the answer to the three questions above?

Comment: play around with the SO question formatting tools, the icons/buttons at the top of the editing box.  Make it easy for us to help you.  Also, if your first question starts with the number 6 some cynics will think that you are asking us to do your homework for you.  If you are, tag your question as such.  Whatever you do, tag your question correctly, there's nothing algorithmic about your question.

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: Added homework tag, as this looks like it is straight out of a textbook, and Ada is just used as a concrete example.

Answer (score 2):

This frequently asked question is meant to highlight the difference between *name equivalence* and *structural equivalence* in a strongly typed language such as [Ada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_%28programming_language%29). For reference, see [*Ada Programming/Type System*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types) and [*Rationale for the Design of the Ada® Programming Language*](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83rat/html/ratl-04-03.html).

Comment: That Type System link is just about perfect for the question. If Ivy's problem is that the supporting material for her question was confusing (or not available somehow), that might help.

Answer (score 1):

We can answer Ada questions fairly well. However, this appears to be a chapter material comprehension question *masquerading* as an Ada question. In particular, a lot depends on how exactly they defined "compatible", "named equivalence", and "structural equivalence". (Although the latter two do have a fairly [well-defined meaning](http://thid.thesa.com/thid-0513-0671-th-0683-5303)) One part of the question is even theoretical based on a facility that Ada does not have. Without that context, it would be tough to answer.

The answer is to be found not in the Ada LRM anywhere, but in the text of your book. Read the chapter, and you should become enlightened.